# YAML deserializer with position information?

Tags: yaml

Does anyone know of a YAML deserializer that can provide position information for the constructed objects?

I know how to deserialize a YAML file into a Java object. Simple instructions on http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/. 
However, I want to do some algorithmic validation on the deserialized object and report error back to the user pointing to the position in the YAML that cause the error.

Example:
=========YAML file==========

```
name: Nathan Sweet
age: 28
address: 4011 16th Ave S
```

=======JAVA class======

```
public class Contact {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String address;
}
```

Imagine if I want to first load the yaml into Contact class and then validate the address against some repository and error back if its invalid. Something like:
'Line 3 Column 9: The address does not match valid entry in the database'

**The problem is, currently there is no way to get the position inside a deserialized object from YAML.**

**Anyone know a solution to this issue?**

Comment: Your question is not tagged Java, does that mean you are open to answers in other languages?

Comment: Yes I am interested in solutions for other languages too ?

Comment: Any Java based solutions ?

Comment: I am also interested in JSON deserializer with position information. The same example should apply except the YAML will not be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Most YAML parsers, if they keep any information about positions around they drop it while constructing the language native objects.

In [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) ¹, I keep more information around because I want to be able to round-trip with minimal loss of original layout (e.g. keeping comments and key order in mappings).

I don't keep information on individual key-value pairs, but I do on the "upper-left" position of a mapping². Because of the kept order of the mapping items you can give some rather nice feedback. Given an input file:

```
- name: anthon
  age: 53
  adres: Rijn en Schiekade 105
- name: Nathan Sweet
  age: 28
  address: 4011 16th Ave S
```

And a program that you call with the input file as argument:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
# coding: utf-8
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677517/yaml-deserializer-with-position-information?noredirect=1#comment49491314_30677517

import sys
import ruamel.yaml

up_arrow = '↑'

def key_error(key, value, line, col, error, e='E'):
    print('E[{}:{}]: {}'.format(line, col, error))
    print('{}{}: {}'.format(' '*col, key, value))
    print('{}{}'.format(' '*(col), up_arrow))
    print('---')


def value_error(key, value, line, col, error, e='E'):
    val_col = col + len(key) + 2
    print('{}[{}:{}]: {}'.format(e, line, val_col, error))
    print('{}{}: {}'.format(' '*col, key, value))
    print('{}{}'.format(' '*(val_col), up_arrow))
    print('---')

def value_warning(key, value, line, col, error):
    value_error(key, value, line, col, error, e='W')

class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, vals):
        for offset, k in enumerate(vals):
            self.check(k, vals[k], vals.lc.line+offset, vals.lc.col)
        for k in ['name', 'address', 'age']:
            if k not in vals:
                print('K[{}:{}]: {}'.format(
                    vals.lc.line+offset, vals.lc.col, "missing key: "+k
                ))
                print('---')


    def check(self, key, value, line, col):
        if key == 'name':
            if value[0].lower() == value[0]:
                value_error(key, value, line, col,
                            'value should start with uppercase')
        elif key == 'age':
            if value < 50:
                value_warning(key, value, line, col,
                              'probably too young for knowing ALGOL 60')
        elif key == 'address':
            pass
        else:
            key_error(key, value, line, col,
                      "unexpected key")

data = ruamel.yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1]), Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)

for x in data:
    contact = Contact(x)
```

giving you E(rrors), W(arnings) and K(eys missing):

```
E[0:8]: value should start with uppercase
  name: anthon
        ↑
---
E[2:2]: unexpected key
  adres: Rijn en Schiekade 105
  ↑
---
K[2:2]: missing key: address
---
W[4:7]: probably too young for knowing ALGOL 60
  age: 28
       ↑
---
```

Which you should be able to parser in a calling program in any language to give feedback. The `check` method of course need adjusting to your requirements. This is not as nice as being to do that in the language the rest of your application is in, but it might be better than nothing.

In my experience handling the above format is certainly simpler than extending an existing (open source) YAML parser.

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of that package</sub>
² <sub>I want to use that kind of information at some point to preserve spurious newlines, inserted for readability</sub>

Comment: The line and column numbers start a 0, for user feedback you might want to add 1 (one) to that.

Comment: This is really nice. However my scenario is different. The feedback I want to give does not come directly from syntactic lookup of yaml, rather I have a complex java code that analyzes the object model and does reporting. That is the reason I would like to create by object model with line numbers for the java pipeline to provide useful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can readily write custom Dumper/Loader objects and use them to load (or dump) your yaml code.  You can have these objects track the file/line info:

```
import yaml
from collections import OrderedDict

class YamlOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    """
    An OrderedDict that was loaded from a yaml file, and is annotated
    with file/line info for reporting about errors in the source file
    """
    def _annotate(self, node):
        self._key_locs = {}
        self._value_locs = {}
        nodeiter = node.value.__iter__()
        for key in self:
            subnode = nodeiter.next()
            self._key_locs[key] = subnode[0].start_mark.name + ':' + \
                                  str(subnode[0].start_mark.line+1)
            self._value_locs[key] = subnode[1].start_mark.name + ':' + \
                                    str(subnode[1].start_mark.line+1)
    def key_loc(self, key):
        try:
            return self._key_locs[key]
        except AttributeError, KeyError:
            return ''
    def value_loc(self, key):
        try:
            return self._value_locs[key]
        except AttributeError, KeyError:
            return ''

# Use YamlOrderedDict objects for yaml maps instead of normal dict
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, lambda dumper, data:
    dumper.represent_dict(data.iteritems()))
yaml.add_representer(YamlOrderedDict, lambda dumper, data:
    dumper.represent_dict(data.iteritems()))
def _load_YamlOrderedDict(loader, node):
    rv = YamlOrderedDict(loader.construct_pairs(node))
    rv._annotate(node)
    return rv
yaml.add_constructor(yaml.resolver.BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG, _load_YamlOrderedDict)
```

Now when you read a yaml file, any mapping objects will be read as a YamlOrderedDict, which allows looking up the file location of keys in the mapping object.  You can also add an iterator method like:

```
def iter_with_lines(self):
    for key, val in self.items():
        yield (key, val, self.key_loc(key))
```

...and now you can write a loop like:

```
for key,value,location in obj.iter_with_lines():
    # iterate through the key/value pairs in a YamlOrderedDict, with
    # the source file location
```

Comment: This is really nice. However my scenario is different. The feedback I want to give does not come directly from syntactic lookup of yaml, rather I have a complex java code that analyzes the object model and does reporting. That is the reason I would like to create by object model with line numbers for the java pipeline to provide useful feedback.